# Add a CollectionView in ScrollView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem in implementing a UI. I actually want to add a collection view at the end of a scroll view. I don't exactly know how to proceed and I think I'm stuck...

Here is my call to add the views in the scroll view.

```html
if training?.description != nil {
  //add description  
  addTraining(description: (training?.description)!)
}
if training?.question1 != nil{
  addTraining(question1: (training?.question1)!)
}
if training?.question2 != nil{
  addTraining(question2: (training?.question2)!)
}
// ADD COLLECTION VIEW AT BOTTOM
```

Here would be the respective functions.

```html
private func addTraining(description: String) {
    trainingDescriptionTitle.text = "Description"
    trainingDescriptionContent.text = description
    trainingDescriptionContent.sizeToFit()
    trainingDescriptionContent.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 10, height: trainingDescriptionContent.frame.height)
    trainingDescriptionContainerView.addView(newView: trainingDescriptionTitle)
    trainingDescriptionContainerView.addView(newView: trainingDescriptionContent)
    scrollView.addView(newView: trainingDescriptionContainerView)
}

private func addTraining(question1: String) {
    trainingQuestion1Title.text = "What You Will Learn"
    trainingQuestion1Content.text = question1
    trainingQuestion1Content.sizeToFit()
    trainingQuestion1Content.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 10, height: trainingQuestion1Content.frame.height)
    trainingQuestion1ContainerView.addView(newView: trainingQuestion1Title)
    trainingQuestion1ContainerView.addView(newView: trainingQuestion1Content)
    scrollView.addView(newView: trainingQuestion1ContainerView)
}

private func addTraining(question2: String) {
    trainingQuestion2Title.text = "Who Should Take This"
    trainingQuestion2Content.text = question2
    trainingQuestion2Content.sizeToFit()
    trainingQuestion2Content.frame.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 10, height: trainingQuestion2Content.frame.height)
    trainingQuestion2ContainerView.addView(newView: trainingQuestion2Title)
    trainingQuestion2ContainerView.addView(newView: trainingQuestion2Content)
    scrollView.addView(newView: trainingQuestion2ContainerView)
}
```

how would I do the same in adding a collectionView in the scrollView?
Thanks to anyone who'll answer.

Here would be the result:

[image]

Comment: maybe it is better to add collectionView as a last row  in tableView? or as a footer

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, that would work. However, I have some more views that would be too complicated to simply put in a cell. Plus, I thought this method would be simpler.